# Adding edges to a hashtable of string and ArrayList

Tags: java, memory, arraylist, hashtable, graph-theory

I am making an adjacencylist using a hashtable. Everything is working OK but what I am trying to do now is to cut down the use of memory.

These are my datatypes. Word is my own class, saving more memory than string:

```
static private Hashtable<Word, ArrayList<Word>> wordlist;
static private Hashtable<Word, Word> wordlist2;
```

I read a file of words and I add the word to my wordlist and also to my 2nd wordlist:

```
static public void Read
.....
wordlist.put(word, new ArrayList<Word>());
wordlist2.put(word,word);
```

Finally I add edges to my wordlist:

```
static public void generateEdges(){
...
wordlist.get(word).add(wordlist2.get(newword));{
```

Ideally I would simply say wordlist.get(word).add(newword); so I wouldn't have to use wordlist2 at all. But I guess the reason that this does not work is because the wordlist has an ArrayList. Can someone think of any alternative ways so I won't have to use wordlist2?

Thanks!

Edit:
Full generateEdges():

```
static public void generateEdges(){
for(Word word : list.keySet()){
Word newword = new Word(Arrays.copyOf(word.charAt, wordLength));
char origChar = word.charAt[0];
int origPos = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++){
    newword.charAt[origPos] = origChar;
    origChar = word.charAt[i];
    origPos = i;
    for (int c = 0; c < alphabet.length; c++){
        if (alphabet[c] != word.charAt[i]) {
            newword.charAt[i] = alphabet[c];
    if (Contains(newword) != null) 
wordlist.get(word).add(wordlist2.get(newword));
                    }}}}}
```

Method for getting the edge of a word:

```
static public ArrayList<Word> getEdges(Word word){
    return wordlist.get(word);
}
```

Comment: Does `wordlist2` really contain identical keys and values (`wordlist2.put(word,word);`) or is it a typo?

Comment: Yes it does @Eran

Comment: I don't see what wordlist2 is good for. wordlist2.get(newword) is identical to newword.

Comment: In that case, it's unclear what you need it for, since `wordlist.get(word).add(wordlist2.get(newword))` is the same as `wordlist.get(word).add(newword)`

Comment: I thought that before aswell. But for some reason it does not work, it only saves one edge and then that's it. I guess it would work if my wordlist looked like: Hashtable<Word, Word>, but I don't think that structure will work since I want an adjacent list. @Eran

Comment: perhaps you are not showing us some of the relevant code that puts data in these two maps.

Comment: Yes that's possible. I have edited my post and added the code that should be relevant under "Edit:" @Eran

Comment: This code is hard to read. Does the Word class override `equals` and `hashCode`? Do you mutate `Word` instances after adding them as keys to your `HashTable`s? Either one could be the reason to your problems.

Comment: It does override those methods, and I do mutate strings to words before adding it to my hashtable @Eran